# ISO vs Folder, which one kills the HDD faster?

Tags: external-hard-drive

I am wondering in what format should I store my data in my external HDD, as ISO or as folder, After storing the data I will read the size of a few video games every 4-5 months.

I convert the folder into ISO on a different dummy drive that I don't care about then copy the ISO over to the external HDD. The folders are moved directly into the external HDD.

Are there any differences between storing them as Folder vs ISO ? Will the folder format which contains a lot of smaller files lower the life of the external HDD vs the ISO format which is just one file ?

Should I be worried about how to store my data? does it make a difference considering I will read the size of a few video games every 4-5 months.

Comment: The real question is: Why?

Comment: Your drive will wear out from old age first.

Comment: Small files will slow down the copying a little bit. Ideally if the files are placed in in adjacent sectors the heads won't have to move much. If they are all over the drive then the heads can wear out faster.

Comment: Only difference might be that it takes one initial read before an ISO image is mounted. However, my inclination is to use folders, because one error in the ISO might make *all* files in it unavailable.

Comment: Also, given that you want to use a dummy drive for the ISO, it means you copy the entire ISO over, thus wear the disk for all content instead of just whatever it is. If you only read from the disk, it won't fragment so a folder is better in every case even though it really is not a big deal.

Comment: You're rather over-thinking this. Drives die when they die. One might last a year, another 12, with the same usage. Just make sure your backups are up to date & stop worrying.